# How can you use jQuery to change all the avatar images' src attribute on Twitter.com systematically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

**TL;DR:** For all "img.avatar" on Twitter.com, I want to replace "_normal.png" for ".png" in the src attribute. See the code and the error I get below.

**Context:** I'm in the process of learning JavaScript and jQuery. So, I like to write small scripts to automate things as practice.

**Problem:** So, I have a Retina MacBook Pro and the 48px avatars on twitter.com look horrible (I know, #firstworldproblem, but bear with me). I noticed that the difference between the URL of the small 48px avatars and the large version is that the former ends with "_normal.png", while the latter simply ends with ".png". Example:

```
48px thumbnail: 
https://blablabla.com/7f11851408ac5220e361a22f1583e0db_normal.png 

Large version: 
https://blablabla.com/7f11851408ac5220e361a22f1583e0db.png
```

This being said, I thought of applying my jQuery knowledge and systematically removing the "_normal" at the end of the src attribute of every avatar image, which can be identified with the "avatar" class. What's the point? Just so that it lo Here's what I tried:

```
jQuery("img.avatar").each( function(){
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("_normal.png", ".png"))
});
```

And here's the error I get in the Console:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is `$(this).attr("src")` undefined, from what I understand of the error?

P.S. I'm relatively new to Stack Exchange, so give me a heads-up if I'm transgressing any conventions.

Comment: Most likely the src attribute isn't initially set. The error you are getting is saying that the src attribute of the selected element is undefined, and you can't call .replace on undefined. Where are you running this code?

Comment: I'm running it directly in the Console from Chrome's Inspect Element tools.

Answer (score 1):

There exist some `img` elements without an `src` attribute in them. This would be what's causing a problem. Try adding a condition before changing the attribute, like so:

```
jQuery("img.avatar").each( function(){
    if($(this).attr('src'))
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("_normal.png", ".png"))
});
```